# EventToCommand issue in MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I have the following visual tree for which I am trying to send a command through the EventToCommand.
The visual is as follow :

```
<Border Background="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand  
                Command="{Binding ShowVideosCmd}" 
                PassEventArgsToCommand="True" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding Videos}">
                    </cmd:EventToCommand>

                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </Border>
```

When clicking on the border where the command is attached to I get the following popup error :

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs' to type
>   'System.Windows.DependencyObject'. "

My command is then created in a viemModel as follow :

```
 ShowVideosCmd = new RelayCommand<DependencyObject>(
     (dpObj) =>
            { 
                 messenger.Default.Send<string>("ShowVideos");
            },
     (dpObj) => true
 );
```

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is quite self explanatory: in you `RelayCommand<DependencyObject>` you've expected the command parameter as a `DependencyObject` but you've got an `MouseButtonEventArgs` which is normal because you've subscribed to the `MouseDown` event.

The `EventToCommand` when the event fires it exectues the command with one of following parameter:

- If the the value of the `CommandParameter` is **NOT** `null` it uses it as the parameter so the command should look like: `RelayCommand<typeOfTheSpecifiedCommandPameter>`
- If the `PassEventArgsToCommand='true'` **and** the value of the
  `CommandParameter` is `null` it uses the eventargs as the command
  parameter. So you need to define your command as
  `RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>`.
- If `PassEventArgsToCommand='false'` **and** the `CommandParameter` is `null` it does **not execute** the command at all.

Note:

So you need to define differently your command for the two cases. At the need you have to use `RelayCommand<object>` and check the parameter type. That's why I think it is bad practice to use `PassEventArgsToCommand` and `CommandParameter` at the same time.

Back to the exception:

In your case it seams `CommandParameter="{Binding Videos}"` returns null that is why you get the `MouseButtonEventArgs` as the command parameter.

To figure out why `{Binding Videos}` is null you can check the Output window in VS during runtime looking for binding errors.