# Passing MouseEvent Args in MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am programming an application where I can crop and resize an image by mouse. Because I had problems figuring out how I could pass Event Args in MVVM, I decided to give MVVM Light a try. Now everytime my mouse is over the image I receive the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.dll
>
> Additional information: Das Objekt des Typs "System.Windows.Point" kann nicht in Typ "System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs" umgewandelt werden.

I don't really know how to fix this although I assume that my RelayCommands are implemented wrong.

I did the bindings in the XAML as following:

```
 <Image x:Name="_image" Margin="10" Source="{Binding CurrentImage.ImagePath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Fill" MaxHeight="300">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=MouseDownCommand}"
                                        EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource MouseButtonEventArgsToPointConverter}"
                                        EventArgsConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=_image}"
                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=MouseMoveCommand}"
                                        EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource MouseEventArgsToPointConverter}"
                                        EventArgsConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=_image}"
                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=MouseUpCommand}"
                                        EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource MouseButtonEventArgsToPointConverter}"
                                        EventArgsConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=_image}"
                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Image>
```

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs> mouseDownCommand;
    public RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs> MouseDownCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mouseDownCommand == null)
            {
                mouseDownCommand = new RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>(MouseDown);
            }
            return mouseDownCommand;
        }
    }

    public void MouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.currentImage.StartPoint = e.GetPosition(this.currentImage.CnvImage);
    }

    RelayCommand<System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs> mouseMoveCommand;
    public RelayCommand<System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs> MouseMoveCommand
    {
      get
        {
            if (mouseMoveCommand == null)
            {
                mouseMoveCommand = new RelayCommand<System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs>(MouseMove);
            }
            return mouseMoveCommand;
        }
    }

    public void MouseMove(System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            var pos = e.GetPosition(this.currentImage.CnvImage);

            var x = Math.Min(pos.X, this.currentImage.StartPoint.X);
            var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, this.currentImage.StartPoint.Y);

            var w = Math.Max(pos.X, this.currentImage.StartPoint.X) - x;
            var h = Math.Max(pos.Y, this.currentImage.StartPoint.Y) - y;

            var rect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle
            {
                Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue,
                StrokeThickness = 2
            };

            this.currentImage.RectSelectArea = rect;

            this.currentImage.RectSelectArea.Width = w;
            this.currentImage.RectSelectArea.Height = h;

            Canvas.SetLeft(this.currentImage.RectSelectArea, x);
            Canvas.SetTop(this.currentImage.RectSelectArea, y);
        }
    }

    RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs> mouseUpCommand;
    public RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs> MouseUpCommand
    {
       get
        {
            if (mouseUpCommand == null)
            {
                mouseUpCommand = new RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>(MouseUp);
            }
            return mouseUpCommand;
        }
    }

    public void MouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.Image croppedImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
        croppedImage.Width = 100;
        croppedImage.Margin = new Thickness(5);

        this.currentImage.CropXPosition = (int)this.currentImage.StartPoint.X;
        this.currentImage.CropYPosition = (int)this.currentImage.StartPoint.Y;
        this.currentImage.CropWidth = (int)this.currentImage.RectSelectArea.Width;
        this.currentImage.CropHeight = (int)this.currentImage.RectSelectArea.Height;
        CroppedBitmap cb = new CroppedBitmap(
            (BitmapSource)this.currentImage.ImagePath, new Int32Rect(
                this.currentImage.CropXPosition, this.currentImage.CropYPosition, this.currentImage.CropWidth, this.currentImage.CropHeight));
        croppedImage.Source = cb;
    }
```

The MouseButtonEventToArgsToPointConverter:

```
  class MouseButtonEventArgsToPointConverter : IEventArgsConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, object parameter)
    {
        var args = (MouseButtonEventArgs)value;
        var element = (FrameworkElement)parameter;

        var point = args.GetPosition(element);
        return point;
    }
}
```

I also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9102277/8794941) advice from a similar question if not same question, but the RelayCommand won't work as a type Point.
How can I fix this? Or is my approach wrong? Really thankful for any kind of help or suggestions.

Comment: MouseButtonEventArgsToPointConverter - can you post the code for this?

Comment: @TimRutter see the Code in the edited post

Comment: You're cramming UI logic into a view model.  MVVM != no codebehind. MVVM separates business logic from UI logic.  Your UI logic belongs in your view's codebehind.  All you're doing is making things harder on yourself with this dance.

Comment: @will I tried doing that but it didn't really work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the `MouseButtonEventArgs` to a Point in the `MouseButtonEventArgsToPointConverter` but the commands are expecting a `MouseButtonEventArgs` parameter - hence the cast exception.  You convert it to a `Point` and then the `Point` is passed to the `RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>`, an attempt is then made to cast `Point` to `MouseButtonEventArgs` which it obviously cannot do.  Do you want to pass the Point or the event args?  If point then change the command to `RelayCommand<Point>`, if event args then remove use of the converter

Either:

```
 <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, 
    Path=MouseDownCommand}"                                        
    EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource MouseButtonEventArgsToPointConverter}"                                         
    EventArgsConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=_image}"
    PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />

public RelayCommand<Point> MouseDownCommand
{
    get
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Also in this case you need to change MouseDown to this:

```
public void MouseDown(Point p)
```

Or:

```
<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, 
    Path=MouseDownCommand}"  PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />

public RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs> MouseDownCommand
{
    get
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah true but I thought that was being needed to get the location of the points so that the image could be cropped. See [here](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/using-the-eventargsconverter-in-mvvm-light-and-why-is-there-no-eventtocommand-in-the-windows-8-1-version/)

Comment: So use the first example above.  If you look at the example in your link the ShowPositionCommand is a RelayCommand<Point> not RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>

Comment: You also need to update your MouseDown function to take a Point - updated answer

Comment: Your second suggestions worked for me. Now the mouse will get the coordinates on the image per click. But now the problem is that my cropping method in MouseMove and MouseDown isn't being executed

Comment: Ok, I've answered your original question.  can you have a go at debugging further?  SO isn't a debugging service like that.  Please upvote and mark as answer if you are satisfied your question has been answered.